# I would like to adjust the distortion at the curve point of the curve modifier

Tags: animation, modifiers

Please see the image.

[image: screenshot of objects]

[image: screenshot of modifier]

I am making Conveyer Animation.
I want to adjust the parts and conveyor to fit as shown in the image.

I have created a single object with two modifiers, 1. Array:Fixed Count and 2.

I am currently adjusting the spacing between the parts using the Relative Offset of the Array Modifier of the parts, but when the Curve is bent, it shifts.

Could you give me a good solution?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the blend file ? https://www.pasteall.org/blend

Comment: Thanks for replay! I added blend file!

Comment: You have not given the same curve as Curve Object for your 2 objects (Belt Conveyer and Parts.001), if you give them both the same Curve Object they will synchronize correctly

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. It worked! thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as @moonboots say, you have two different curves for the two objects, by using the same curve (I used `Belt Curve` for the two), they synchronize :

[image]

Also, your animations don't line up, the cubes went clockwise while the belt goes anticlockwise so I reversed the cube's animation to follow the belt.

Comment: Sorry for late reply..  Thank you so much!! It perfectly  worked!

Comment: You're welcome.